# Unknown provider: $routeParamsProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

I'm going through the AngularJS [PhoneCat tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/) and while the application seems to behave correctly when I click through it manually, one of the unit tests are failing for [step 8](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_08).

Using [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html), I'm getting the following console output:

> Chrome 42.0.2311 (Windows 7) PhoneCat controllers PhoneDetailCtrl
>   should fetch phone detail FAILED  Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown
>   provider: $routeParamsProvider <- $routeParams

The relevant part of the unit test file (controllersSpec.js) looks like this:

```
describe("PhoneCat controllers", function () {
    describe('PhoneDetailCtrl', function () {
        var scope, $httpBackend, ctrl;

        beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $routeParams, $controller) {        
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
            $httpBackend.expectGET('phones/xyz').respond({ name: 'phone xyz' });
            $routeParams.phoneId = 'xyz';
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            ctrl = $controller('PhoneDetailCtrl', { $scope: scope });
        }));
    });
});
```

The problem seems to be related to the declaration of the function parameter of the call to `inject()`. If I take $routeParams out then the script will execute.

From reading some related StackOverflow questions it seems I might be missing a dependency somewhere. The relevant parts of the karma.conf.js file look like this:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        files: [
            '../lib/angular/angular.js',
            '../lib/angular/angular-mocks.js',
            '../lib/angular/angular-route.js',
            '../app/*.js',
            'unit/*.js'
        ],
        browsers: ['Chrome'],
        singleRun: false
    });
};
```

My app.js looks like this:

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module("phonecatApp", [
    "ngRoute",
    "phonecatControllers"]);

phonecatApp.config([
    "$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/phones", {
                templateUrl: "Scripts/app/partials/phone-list.html",
                controller: "PhoneListCtrl"
            })
            .when("/phones/:phoneId", {
                templateUrl: "Scripts/app/partials/phone-detail.html",
                controller: "PhoneDetailCtrl"
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: "/phones"
            });
    }
]);
```

And controllers.js looks like this:

```
var phonecatControllers = angular.module("phonecatControllers", []);

phonecatControllers.controller("PhoneDetailCtrl", ["$scope", "$routeParams", "$http", function ($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $http.get("api/Phones/" + $routeParams.phoneId).success(function (data) {
        $scope.phone = data;
    });
}]);
```

As mentioned at the top, the app seems to work fine when I click through it in the browser so I'm quite confused as to where things are breaking down for the unit tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is often the case with these kind of errors, the fix is pretty obvious when you see it! Basically there are two functions in controllersSpec.js, one for a list of phones and one for an individual phone's details. The phone list tests were working fine because they had
`beforeEach(module("phonecatApp"));` before the call to `beforeEach(inject(function ());`

The phone detail tests on the other hand were missing this line. Once I moved the line to the outer function the tests passed as expected.
The working controllersSpec.js looks like this:

```
describe("PhoneCat controllers", function () {
    // This is the line that was moved.
    // It existed for PhoneListCtrl but not PhoneDetailCtrl.    
    beforeEach(module("phonecatApp"));

    describe("PhoneListCtrl", function() {
        var scope, ctrl, $httpBackend;

        beforeEach(module("phonecatApp"));

        beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller) {
            // Setup
        }));
        // Various tests
    });

    describe('PhoneDetailCtrl', function () {
        var scope, $httpBackend, ctrl;

        beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $routeParams, $controller) {
            // Setup
        }));

        // Various tests
    });
});
```

Comment: You can have just one `beforeEach(inject(function()....` in the parent describe block with the vars like this: http://jsfiddle.net/hravc0g6/1/